# JFrame, JPanel, paintComponent how to

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

1. Hi I have following classes, I want display content
   (paintComponentor that panel with this rectangle from paint class)
   inside my JFrame. I try already find out how to achieve this by
   looking at different examples posted on this forum however this
   doesn't help me I need simple example like panel inside frame with
   paint component or something similar to understand how should work!
       ps. don't hang me on tree because I am newbie jut ask question!!!

   [I want something like this][1]

   ```
   package scp;

   import java.awt.*;

   import javax.swing.*;

   public class Panel extends JPanel {
       public Panel() {
           //this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
           //panel = new Panel();
           setVisible(true);
           setLayout(new FlowLayout());
           setSize(200, 300);
           getRootPane();
       }
       @Override
       public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
           g.drawString("HEY",20,20);
           g.drawRect(200, 200, 200, 200); 
       }

   }

   and

   package scp;

   import javax.swing.JFrame;
   import javax.swing.JButton;

   import java.awt.Color;
   import java.awt.FlowLayout;
   import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
   import java.beans.EventHandler;

   public class Frame extends JFrame {

       JButton redButton;
       JButton blueButton;

       public Frame()
       {
           super("EventHandling");
           setLayout(new FlowLayout());
           redButton = new JButton("Red");
           add(redButton);
           blueButton = new JButton("Blue");
           add(blueButton);

           EventHandler h = new EventHandler();

           redButton.addActionListener(h);
           blueButton.addActionListener(h);

       }

       private class EventHandler implements ActionListener
       {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {
               if (e.getSource()==redButton)
                   getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
               else if(e.getSource()==blueButton)
                   getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
           }
       }

   }

   and

   package scp;

   import javax.swing.JFrame;

   public class EventHandling {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

           Frame f = new Frame();
           f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           f.setSize(800,600);
           f.setVisible(true);
           f.getContentPane().add(new Panel());
       }

   }
   ```

   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJTrq.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by taking a look at:

- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

This is probably the simplest I can make it...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int width = getWidth() - 100;
            int height = getHeight() - 100;
            int x = (getWidth() - width) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - height) / 2;
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

**Compound Example**

This example uses an `outer` panel, which has an empty border applied to it, this pushes the content of the edges of the `outer` panel.

The inner panel (which is unchanged from the last example), as a light gray border applied to it so you can see it, the red rectangle is still been painted by the panels `paintComponent` method.

[image: Compound]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JPanel outer = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) {
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(400, 400);
                    }
                };

                outer.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(50, 50, 50, 50));

                TestPane tp = new TestPane();
                tp.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY));

                outter.add(tp);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(outer);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int width = getWidth() - 100;
            int height = getHeight() - 100;
            int x = (getWidth() - width) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - height) / 2;
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: this red square is actually printed by paint component right? hmm what about if this red rectangle will be panel that hold anchart or image??

Comment: The red square is painted within the bounds of the panel, which is inside a frame. In this example, the red square is always 100 pixels smaller than the surround panel.

Comment: so if I add another panel that will for example hold a text, that red rectangle will be in the same position inside  panel  doesn't mater where that panel will lay on layout ?

Comment: Based on the example above, the red rectangle will be centered within the component and will always be 100 pixels smaller than the component itself, so, no, the red rectangle will change position based on the size of the component...

Comment: OK, that put some light on this. I will go trough that links what you gave me and I will inspect this two examples. Thank You MadProgrammer

Comment: Try moving the rectangle and/or fixing it's size and see what you get ;)

Comment: oh I see  when I resize window the rectangle is resized also but when I set fixed values the rectangle remain on its position so getWidth and height takes values of actual size of the window

Comment: Actual size of the component, not the window itself ;)