# JFrame paint glitch?

Tags: java, jframe

So this is my code:

```
package project;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Project extends JFrame {
String thing = "none";
int x = 100;
int y = 100; 
int w = 1600;
int h = 800;
int ww = 5;
int hh = 5;
public class AL extends KeyAdapter{
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int KeyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if (KeyCode == e.VK_NUMPAD1){
            downleft();
            if (thing == "none" || thing == "d" || thing == "dr" || thing == "l" || thing == "r" ||
                    thing == "ul" || thing == "u" || thing == "ur") {
                thing = "dl";
                System.out.println("Drawing down to the left!");
            }
        }
        if (KeyCode == e.VK_NUMPAD2){
            down();
            if (thing == "none" || thing == "dl" || thing == "dr" || thing == "l" || thing == "r" ||
                    thing == "ul" || thing == "u" || thing == "ur") {
                thing = "d";
            System.out.println("Drawing down!");
            }
        }
        if (KeyCode == e.VK_NUMPAD3){
            downright();
            if (thing == "none" || thing == "dl" || thing == "d" || thing == "l" || thing == "r" ||
                    thing == "ul" || thing == "u" || thing == "ur") {
                thing = "dr";
            System.out.println("Drawing down to the right!");
            }
        }
        if (KeyCode == e.VK_NUMPAD4){
            left();
            if (thing == "none" || thing == "dl" || thing == "d" || thing == "dr" || thing == "r" ||
                    thing == "ul" || thing == "u" || thing == "ur") {
                thing = "l";
            System.out.println("Drawing to the left");
            }
        }
        if (KeyCode == e.VK_NUMPAD6){
            right();
            if (thing == "none" || thing == "dl" || thing == "d" || thing == "dr" || thing == "l" ||
                    thing == "ul" || thing == "u" || thing == "ur") {
                thing = "r";
            System.out.println("Drawing to the right!");
            }
        }
        if (KeyCode == e.VK_NUMPAD7){
            upleft();
            if (thing == "none" || thing == "dl" || thing == "d" || thing == "dr" || thing == "l" ||
                    thing == "r" || thing == "u" || thing == "ur") {
                thing = "ul";
            System.out.println("Drawing up to the left!");
            }
        }
        if (KeyCode == e.VK_NUMPAD8){
            up();
            if (thing == "none" || thing == "dl" || thing == "d" || thing == "dr" || thing == "l" ||
                    thing == "r" || thing == "ul" || thing == "ur") {
                thing = "u";
            System.out.println("Drawing up!");
            }
        }
        if (KeyCode == e.VK_NUMPAD9){
            upright();
            if (thing == "none" || thing == "dl" || thing == "d" || thing == "dr" || thing == "l" ||
                    thing == "r" || thing == "ul" || thing == "u") {
                thing = "ur";
            System.out.println("Drawing up to the right!");
            }
        }
        if (KeyCode == e.VK_B){
            ww += 5;
            hh += 5;
            System.out.println("Resized! It is now " + ww + " by " + hh + "!");
            if (ww > 150) {
                ww = 150;
                hh = 150;
                System.out.println("The size went too high! Resized back to 150 by 150!");
            }
        }
        if (KeyCode == e.VK_S){
            ww -= 5;
            hh -= 5;
            System.out.println("Resized! It is now " + ww + " by " + hh + "!");
            if (ww < 5) {
                ww = 5;
                hh = 5;
                System.out.println("The size went too low! Resized back to 5 by 5!");
            }
        }
    }
}
public void downleft(){
    x-=5;
    y+=5;
}
public void down(){
    y+=5;
}
public void downright(){
    x+=5;
    y+=5;
}
public void left(){
    x-=5;
}
public void right(){
    x+=5;
}
public void upleft(){
    x-=5;
    y-=5;
}
public void up(){
    y-=5;
}
public void upright(){
    x+=5;
    y-=5;
}
public Project(){
    addKeyListener(new AL());
    setTitle("Escher Sketch");
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(w, h);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.fillRect(x, y, ww, hh);
    repaint();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Project();
}
}
```

For some reason when I run it it's just a black window with a small white rectanble in the top left corner. I read over the code a lot of times and it really seems like it should work. It was working on my other computer then i tried putting the file on this computer and it didn't. If anyone could help me that would be great.

Comment: Do both computers have similar versions of Java installed? My understanding is that at times exporting Java code can cause it to fail working on some machines due to its encoding.

Comment: I know the one it's not working on has the latest version, but I'm not sure about the one I made it on.

Comment: a. It is not recommended to paint on a JFrame... Rather, paint on a JPanel, and add that to a JFrame's contentpane. <br>b. don't call repaint in your paint method. Instead, use something like the swing Timer class to do scheduled repainting

Comment: Never call repaint() from a paint method.  Doing so creates an infinite loop (though not a direct loop), since repaint() causes paint to be called.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from the `Project()` part into this:

```
public Project(){
    addKeyListener(new AL());
    setTitle("Escher Sketch");
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(w, h);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().add(new MyGraphics());
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Project();
}
class MyGraphics extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.fillRect(x, y, ww, hh);
        repaint();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why you dont use a Panel instead of applying the paint to the JFrame itself

here some ref :

[JFrame, JPanel, paintComponent how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27179739/jframe-jpanel-paintcomponent-how-to)

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JPanelpaintComponentGraphicsg.htm

## Note that if you want to refresh the panel call `repaint();`