# Error: cannot find symbol "super.paintComponent(brush);" being run in non-inner class

Tags: java, jframe, repaint, super, cannot-find-symbol

This code is not in an inner class, as far as I can tell, and the only relevant question I can find is regarding when this code is ran in an inner class.

Relevant code:

```
public JDemoLocation()
{
   setTitle("Fireworks");
   setLayout(new FlowLayout());
   setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   add(button);
   button.addActionListener(this);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics brush)
{
   super.paintComponent(brush);
   if (drawIt)
   {
      x = 450;
      y = 500;
      z = 250;
```

Full code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JDemoLocation extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
   JButton button = new JButton("Fire!");
   int y = 50;
   int x = 50;
   int z = 500;
   int v = 500;
   boolean drawIt = false;

   final int GAP = 30;

   public JDemoLocation()
   {
      setTitle("Fireworks");
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      add(button);
      button.addActionListener(this);
   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics brush)
   {
      super.paintComponent(brush);
      if (drawIt)
      {
         x = 450;
         y = 500;
         z = 250;
         v = 500;
         brush.drawLine(z, v, x, y);
         x = 550;
         y = 500;
         z = 750;
         v = 500;
         brush.drawLine(z, v, x, y);
         x = 500;
         y = 550;
         z = 500;
         v = 750;
         brush.drawLine(z, v, x, y);
         x = 500;
         y = 450;
         z = 500;
         v = 250;
         brush.drawLine(z, v, x, y);
         x = 550;
         y = 450;
         z = 750;
         v = 250;
         brush.drawLine(z, v, x, y);
         x = 550;
         y = 550;
         z = 750;
         v = 750;
         brush.drawLine(z, v, x, y);
         x = 450;
         y = 550;
         z = 250;
         v = 750;
         brush.drawLine(z, v, x, y);
         x = 450;
         y = 450;
         z = 250;
         v = 250;
         brush.drawLine(z, v, x, y);
         int xPoints[] = {502, 512, 532, 512, 520, 500, 475, 488, 469, 492, 502};
         int yPoints[] = {468, 492, 498, 510, 535, 515, 532, 505, 488, 490, 468};
         brush.drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, xPoints.length);
      }
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
      drawIt = true;
      repaint();
   }


public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      JDemoLocation frame = new JDemoLocation();
      frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Assuming what I think is right, then the portion with paintComponent is not in an inner-class or anonymous class, and doesn't need the "qualifier", which doesn't work for me either...

**EDIT**

Ok I got it now thanks.

Comment: It's not an inner class problem at all - it's that there's no such method as `paintComponent` in JFrame. Have a look at the documentation... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JFrame` is not a `JComponent`, it doesn't have a paintComponent method you can override. Instead you could extend a `JPanel` and add it to the frame.

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27179775/490502 for sample code

Comment: Thanks Entea, I've made progress, but now the drawing won't display until I maximize the window for some reason.

Comment: Never mind, got it now. Had the new frame in the wrong place before the button. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your base class, [`JFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html), does not have a method named `paintComponent()`.